# NAudio 2-channels waves to graphics

Tags: graphics, naudio

Good day, colleagues! 
Help, the head has already broken ... 
the following code I get a wave from the WAV file and output it in Graphics ... I'm betting on how to split the output of the graph on the left and right channel ... please ...! Tried to taste the manual on NAudio but so did not understand anything about what I need ...

```
#region draw container
        SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, 0, 0, this.Width-2, this.Height-2);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, 0, this.Width-2, 0);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, this.Height / 2, this.Width-2, this.Height / 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, this.Height - 2, this.Width-2, this.Height-2);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 0, 0, 0, this.Height-2);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, this.Width-2, 0, this.Width-2, this.Height-2);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("L:", new Font("Arial", 6, FontStyle.Bold), blackBrush, 2, 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("R:", new Font("Arial", 6, FontStyle.Bold), blackBrush, 2, (this.Height /2) + 2);
        #endregion
        if (waveStream != null)
        {
            waveStream.Position = 0;
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] waveData = new byte[samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample];
            waveStream.Position = startPosition + (e.ClipRectangle.Left * bytesPerSample * samplesPerPixel);

            Pen linePen_L = new Pen(PenColor_L, PenWidth);
            Pen linePen_R = new Pen(PenColor_R, PenWidth);
            //bool _left = true; bool _right = false;
            for (float x = e.ClipRectangle.X; x < e.ClipRectangle.Right; x += 1)
            {
                //_left = !_left;
                //_right = !_right;

                short low = 0;
                short high = 0;
                bytesRead = waveStream.Read(waveData, 0, samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;
                for (int n = 0; n < bytesRead; n += 2)
                {
                    short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(waveData, n);
                    if (sample < low) low = sample;
                    if (sample > high) high = sample;
                }
                float lowPercent = ((((float)low) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                float highPercent = ((((float)high) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                //if (_left)
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(linePen_L, x, (this.Height * lowPercent) /2, x, (this.Height * highPercent)/2);
                //if (_right)
                    //e.Graphics.DrawLine(linePen_R, x, ((this.Height * lowPercent) /2) + this.Height/2, x, ((this.Height * highPercent) /2) + this.Height / 2);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way :)

```
            if (waveStream != null)
        {
            waveStream.Position = 0;
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] waveData = new byte[samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample];
            waveStream.Position = startPosition + (e.ClipRectangle.Left * bytesPerSample * samplesPerPixel);

            Pen linePen_L = new Pen(PenColor_L, PenWidth);
            Pen linePen_R = new Pen(PenColor_R, PenWidth);
            for (float x = e.ClipRectangle.X; x < e.ClipRectangle.Right; x += 1)
            {
                short low_L = 0;
                short high_L = 0;
                short low_R = 0;
                short high_R = 0;
                bytesRead = waveStream.Read(waveData, 0, samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                    break;
                for (int n = 0; n < bytesRead; n += 2)
                {
                    short sample_L = BitConverter.ToInt16(waveData, n);
                    if (sample_L < low_L) low_L = sample_L;
                    if (sample_L > high_L) high_L = sample_L;
                    n += 2;

                    short sample_R = BitConverter.ToInt16(waveData, n);
                    if (sample_R < low_R) low_R = sample_R;
                    if (sample_R > high_R) high_R = sample_R;
                }
                float lowPercent_L = ((((float)low_L) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                float highPercent_L = ((((float)high_L) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);

                float lowPercent_R = ((((float)low_R) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                float highPercent_R = ((((float)high_R) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(linePen_L, x, (this.Height * lowPercent_L) / 2, x, (this.Height * highPercent_L) / 2);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(linePen_R, x, ((this.Height * lowPercent_R) / 2) + this.Height / 2, x, ((this.Height * highPercent_R) / 2) + this.Height / 2);
            }

        }
```